# Cassandra 3.11 crashing on Windows 10 when started by cassandra-maven-plugins with Java 11

Tags: cassandra, windows-10, java-11

I have integration test in `maven verify`, that starts Apache Cassandra 3.11.13. I'm using `cassandra-maven-plugin` 3.7. I tried moving the project to Java 11. After adding Java 11 vm options to `cassandra-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>    
                    <addJdk11Options>${runningJava11}</addJdk11Options>
                    .....
```

I've got Cassandra to start on Linux, but on Windows was crashing, unfortunately without logs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to craft the same JVM parameters used by the `cassandra-maven-plugin`, but added the `slf4j-jdk14-1.7.32.jar` to the class path. The JVM parameters can be printed when starting `mvn -X`, however the class path and main class can be found in git\software-app\target\cassandra\bin\cassandra.jar which is packed by the `cassandra-maven-plugin`. In the logs I found this error:

```
Aug 20, 2022 9:32:12 PM org.apache.cassandra.service.DefaultFSErrorHandler handleStartupFSError
SEVERE: Exiting forcefully due to file system exception on startup, disk failure policy "stop"

Aug 20, 2022 9:32:12 PM org.apache.cassandra.service.DefaultFSErrorHandler handleStartupFSError
SEVERE: Exiting forcefully due to file system exception on startup, disk failure policy "stop"
FSWriteError in C:\Users\pesho\git\software-app\target\cassandra\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377\me-8-big-Data.db
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogTransaction.delete(LogTransaction.java:261)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogTransaction$SSTableTidier.run(LogTransaction.java:386)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$GlobalTidy.tidy(SSTableReader.java:2333)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$GlobalState.release(Ref.java:326)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State.release(Ref.java:225)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref.release(Ref.java:119)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$InstanceTidier$1.run(SSTableReader.java:2238)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:84)

        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\pesho\git\software-app\target\cassandra\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377\me-8-big-Data.db
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:274)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:105)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1142)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogTransaction.delete(LogTransaction.java:243)
        ... 13 more
```

It seems Cassandra is trying to delete a file, that is still open for reading. I was able to start Cassandra after modifying `target/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml` by setting:

```
disk_failure_policy: ignore
```

Since this a this a test only instance, I decided, I'm fine with this option.
Unfortunately this yaml file is generated by `cassandra-maven-plugin`. After some digging in the code of the plugin, I found the `yaml` parameter, which merges configs from pom.xml and default config file:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- required to start on Windows -->
                    <yaml>disk_failure_policy: ignore</yaml>    
                    <addJdk11Options>${runningJava11}</addJdk11Options>
                    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java file I/O library that Cassandra uses has always been problematic on Windows particularly with NTFS. It has been a constant source of issues for users that we decided it wasn't good for the project to continue support (see the [discussion in this thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread/cpbpx74ysrs7xwgklpx2wh6003jms260)).

We eventually dropped Windows support completely in Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)).

Also, Cassandra 3.1x (and earlier versions) only work with Java 8 (see [Cassandra installation prerequisites](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html)). Cassandra 4.0.2 added full support (previously experimental) for Java 11 only recently ([CASSANDRA-16894](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16894)). This means that C* 4.x will work with either Java 8 or Java 11.

The recommended workarounds for Windows users are:

- Deploy [Cassandra in Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using software like VirtualBox
- Deploy Cassandra in a Kubernetes cluster with [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

Otherwise if you just want to learn how to build apps on Cassandra, [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) has a free tier where you can launch a cluster in just 5 clicks. Cheers!

Comment: I'm aware that Windows support was officially dropped, however when forced to do developing on Windows due to company polices, it is nice to be able to run some unit tests on my laptop and be able to easily debug, without the burden on configuring everything on docker etc...